# Calling external rest resources within confluence atlassian wiki

Tags: rest, api, confluence

I want to call external rest resource from within confluence atlassian wiki .

Any examples ?

Can this be achieved via CLI in the backend ?

Please kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: when you say 'from within', what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: @sendmoreinfo i mean i have a wiki page (say host A)- i want to make a rest call (say host B) which will retrieve some html data from the backend. I want to display that html data in host A page

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need this is a warning sign about the design of your app. The plugin api is way more powerful than the REST api and you should lern to use it.

Technically, what you want is possible, but you may have a problem with authentication. When you try to reach the web interface from the backend, you have to log in as a user, you will not be automatically logged in as the backend user. You also need to have access to the url, which is not automatic in corporte environment with all kinds of complex networks solutions.

Comment: authentication is not a problem that rest call is a unauthenticated html page served from a jboss instance. Rest call will return back html page

Answer (score 0):

If the rest service is unauthenticated then you could look to [Enable the html-include macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Enabling+the+html-include+Macro).

Which would allow you to do an html include of the GET REST service call within the page.

Would look like this once enabled:

```
{html-include:url=http://www.example.com/rest/myservice?param1=1}
```

However, I suggest looking to use [their whitelist feature](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+the+Whitelist) if you do this.

This also only works for self hosted instances and not for on-demand.